# Boost::any reference to stored value not compiling

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I'm trying to write a generic configuration class that holds parameters like this (simplified greatly):

```
class Parameter
{
public:
   Parameter(boost::any value, bool isRequired) 
     : value(value), isRequired(isRequired) {}
   bool isSet;
   bool isRequired;
   boost::any value;
};

class ParameterGroup
{
public:
   map<std::string, Parameter> table;
   // references for chaining
   ParameterGroup& add_parameter_group(const string &token, const bool isRequired);
   ParameterGroup& add_parameter(const string &token, const bool isRequired);

   template<typename T>
   T& get_parameter(const string &token);
};
```

The problem is in the `add_parameter_group` function:

```
ParameterGroup& ParameterGroup::add_parameter_group(const string &token, 
                                                    const bool &isRequired)
{
   table[token] = Parameter(ParameterGroup(), isRequired);
   return boost::any_cast<ParameterGroup>(table[token].value);
}
```

The return fails to compile with the message

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ParameterGroup& from an 
       rvalue of type ParameterGroup
```

I don't see why. According to the `boost::any_cast` documentation:

> If passed a pointer, it returns a similarly qualified pointer to the value content if successful, otherwise null is returned. If T is ValueType, it returns a copy of the held value, otherwise, if T is a reference to (possibly const qualified) ValueType, it returns a reference to the held value.

Why is this failing to return a reference as it seems it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is not a reference type, but `ValueType`, so according to the documentation you quoted, you get a value.

You are then trying to bind this [temporary] value to a ref-to-non-`const`.

The clause you are trying to activate is:

> if `T` is a reference to (possibly const qualified) `ValueType`, it returns a reference to the held value.

So, let's make `T` a reference to `ValueType`:

```
boost::any_cast<ParameterGroup&>(table[token].value);
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//              |------------||
//                ValueType (ref)
//              |-------------|
//                     T
```

Now you'll get a reference to the held value, which'll bind just fine to the return type.

Comment: Ah wow. I am going to go in a corner somewhere and quietly kick myself. That seems so obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @Fadecomic: It happens. :-)

Comment: @Fadecomic I disagree. Your question helped me. Extracting a ref should have been an example in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Directly taken from [boost::any header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any/reference.html#header.boost.any_hpp)

```
  template<typename T> T any_cast(any &);
  template<typename T> T any_cast(const any &);
  template<typename ValueType> const ValueType * any_cast(const any *);
  template<typename ValueType> ValueType * any_cast(any *);
```

So you see that boost::any_cast returns a copy when you ask for a value, that is why you cant return a reference. So try any_cast with casting a reference

Comment: Well, no; it depends on what `T` is, as the documentation says.